# DetailView not created in UISplitView

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to create UISplitView programmatically after pressing a button in a view. For UISplitView, I have two view controllers called as `MyTableViewController` and `MyDetailViewController`. This is what I am doing in the action of the button:

```
UISplitViewController* splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
MyTableViewController* firstVC = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
MyDetailViewController* secondVC = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *leftNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[leftNavController pushViewController:firstVC animated:NO];

splitVC.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftNavController, secondVC, nil];

AppDelegate * appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window setRootViewController:splitVC];
```

But secondVC (the detail view) doesn't show up. It is just black. Though, the firstVC (the table view) shows up as it should be. What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you have an interface set up for the detail view controller in a nib or storyboard?

Comment: both the table and the detail view interface are in storyboard and their class attributes are set respectively.

Comment: Take a look at using `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewIdentifier"]` or whatever identifier you have for the detail view, because `init` won't ever ask the storyboard for setup.

Comment: I thought giving the classes were enough. Thanks it works now. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: The table view shows up because a UITableViewController automatically comes with one, but a UIViewController only comes with an empty black view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at using `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewIdentifier"]`, and set an identifier for the view controller in your storyboard. Calling `init` on a view controller doesn't reference the storyboard you have created, so you need to instead pull the view controller out of the storyboard. The table view worked because its layout is programmed into the `UITableViewController` class.